# Why the accuracy of svm in python and Matlab are different?

Tags: python, matlab, classification, svm

I apply svm on a dataset , and i reached to the accuracy of 100 percent!
but when I use matlab classifier app , I reache to 98.8 percent of accuracy .
in both of them the kernel is RBF . 
in python I use 20 percent of data as test and 80 percent of data as train data.
can anyone explain this ?

```
all_data = pd.read_csv('data.csv', header=0, lineterminator="\n")
all_data = shuffle(all_data,random_state= 20)
all_data = all_data.apply(LabelEncoder().fit_transform)
data = np.array(all_data.drop('g', axis=1), dtype=np.float32)
labels = np.array(all_data['g'])
train_data = data[:200]
train_lable = labels[:200]
test_data = data[200:]
test_lable = labels[200:]
class_names = [25]
clf = svm.SVC(gamma=0.001)
clf.fit(train_data, train_lable)
score = clf.score(test_data,test_lable)
print(score)
```

Comment: Is every setting the same? The difference is minimaal regardless tho

Comment: I don't know how matlab split the data for train and test data , so maybe ther is some difference in train and test data , and the kernel is same , and other settings are default .

Comment: Well there's ya answer; match the settings and you will get the same performance.

Comment: after a lot of search (I'm beginner in ML and etc.) here is the settings in python and Matlab: in python + kernel : RBF , using one-vs-one method(the default of svm according to sklearn doc is one-vs-one) , gamma = 0.0001 . IN MATLAB + kernel : Gaussian(after some searching i realized that this two (RBF and Gaussian ) are same .using one-vs-one method ,kernel scale is 0.94 . Box constraint level: 1 (I don't know how to change this in python I can't find anything in doc of svm in sklearn . and when I change the gamma to 0.94 or higher the Accuracy decreases from 100% to something like 40%.

Answer (score 0):

1. It is possible that there may be some applicational difference between two libraries of Matlab and Python.
2. SVM is sensitive to float accuracy, so I guess it's because of the difference  in floating point numbers in Matlab and Python. If you force matlab to do the calculations as uint64, you'll probably find a closer answer.

It's better to ask questions in [datascience forum](http://datascience.stackexchange.com).